# Altering the definition of a function without an assignment

Tags: python

I was given this task:

> Write a one-line expression that transforms an f(x) function into f(x)
>   +1. Hint: think about how a local frame binding for saved value of f, can be created **without an assignment**.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> >>> f = lambda x: x*x
> >>> f(5) 25
> >>> ---your one line expression---
> >>> f(5) 26
> >>> f, g = None, f
> >>> g(5) 26
> ```

I tried to do this:

```
k,f=f, lambda x: k(x)+1
```

And it works but it uses the assignment `f=f`. How could I do this without an assignment?

My teacher told me that there is a function in Python similar to the `let` function in Scheme, but I'm not sure what this function is that she wants us to use because she did not provide the name of the function.

Comment: Please post the code you tried that didn't work, so we can help you solve the problem with your code.

Comment: `g = lambda x: f(x)+1` ?

Comment: @BhargavRao isn't `g = ...` an assignment?

Comment: @ReutSharabani Now that the OP has edited ...

Comment: `(lambda x: k(x)+1)(5)` will print `26` and will have to be written completely every where it is used

Comment: @BhargavRao it wasn't an edit? It's been there the whole time

Comment: @BhargavRao I think the problem is not to come up with an expression that evaluates to f(x)+1, but to modify the existing function f so that it returns f(x)+1. And frankly, I'm stumped on that

Comment: @SterlingArcher Grace period edit, perhaps.

Comment: @JonKiparsky Oh, Is it so? Shouldn't the OP have clarified a bit more?

Comment: @BhargavRao I think the poster was pretty clear: "write a one-line expression that transforms an f(x) function into f(x) +1"

Comment: Also the title: *how to avoid assignment in pyton*

Comment: @BhargavRao I think that: g = lambda x: f(x)+1 is a assignment

Comment: @user3223332 Yeah, that was the whole point of discussion. **Sorry**. There are already great answers that have come up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work, but it may be cheating:

```
>>> f = lambda x: x*x
>>> f(5)
25
>>> globals().update({'f': (lambda g: lambda x: g(x)+1)(f)})
>>> f(5)
26
>>> f, g = None, f
>>> g(5)
26
```

Comment: Nice workaround :-) you could also use a doubly nested lambda to avoid updating globals/locals with more than one name: `locals().update({"f": (lambda g: lambda x: g(x)+1)(f)})`

Comment: @Kevin: Ah yes nice! That makes it equivalent to the other answer. I'll update it to do that, thanks

Comment: @Kevin "Yo dawg, I heard you hate assignment operators, so I put a lambda in your lambda so you can assign without assigning"

Comment: Interestingly if I did `globals().update({'f': lambda x, g=f: g(x)+1})` it'd be exactly equivalent to the `def f(x, g=f): return g(x)+1` solution

Answer (score 10):

This is not something that should be used in general, but I suppose you could do this:

```
def f(x, f=f): return f(x) + 1
```

And there's "no (explicit) assignments" since we're just defining a new function name which happens to be the same as the original.

Comment: Ah yes I think this is what he was looking for

Comment: @Claudiu I'm a little sad that you removed your answer. It's cheating, yes, but it does answer the question.

Comment: @JonKiparsky: I had removed it because it didn't work after the `f, g = None, f` line, but I changed it to work in that case as well and undeleted it.

Comment: Isn't this: `f=f` an assignment? (great answer by the way)

Comment: @ReutSharabani: Technically no, we're binding a value to a parameter as a default. They're not quite the same.